# Passing a Terraform provider alias to a module from the "main.tf"

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am new to terraform. I have the following directory structure for both `shared-env` and `dev` environments - I have removed other files (variables.tf, variables.tfvars etc) for simplicity

shared-env/

- shared.tf

dev/

- dev.tf

modules/

- main.tf

and in the `dev.tf`, I have the following code:

```
module "azurevpn-keyvault" {
  source = "../modules"

  resource_group_name = "${var.environment}-vault-azurevpn"
  keyvault_name       = "${var.environment}-vault-azurevpn"
  location            = module.global_variables.default_region

  pep           = true 
  a_record      = true
  dns_zone_name = module.vaultcore_privatelink.dns_zone_name
  dns_zone_rg   = module.global_variables.infrastructure_rg
  pep_subnet_id = module.vnet-backend.vnet_subnets.pep-vault.id

  . . . 

  tags = var.default_tags
}
```

And in the `main.tf` in the modules directory, here's what I have - here also I have given the `provider{}` section with the values for a different azure `subscription`

```
resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "keyvault_pep_record" {
  
  count               = var.a_record ? 1 : 0
  name                = var.keyvault_name
  zone_name           = var.dns_zone_name
  resource_group_name = var.dns_zone_rg
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [resource.azurerm_private_endpoint.keyvault_pep[0].private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
}


provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "shared_env"
  features {}
  subscription_id = "<RETRACTED>"
  tenant_id       = "<RETRACTED>"
}

// only this below resource should be created in the "shared_env"

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "keyvault_shared_env_pep_record" {
  provider            = azurerm.shared_env
  
  count               = var.a_record ? 1 : 0
  name                = var.keyvault_name
  zone_name           = var.dns_zone_name
  resource_group_name = var.dns_zone_rg
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [resource.azurerm_private_endpoint.keyvault_pep[0].private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
}
```

according to the above, everything is working fine. But I want to know if this is the correct way of doing this.

I also have seen this [terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers#passing-providers-explicitly) document. According to this, I can also pass it as `configuration_aliases`, but still having some doubts as I am a new learner of `terraform`

Comment: So is there anything wrong with the code? Are there any errors? Undesired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried Passing a Terraform provider alias to a module from the "main.tf for a test case mentioned as per the requirement.

Since you don't mention any blocker in this query I tried to troubleshoot the code which seems to be on the right track. However, there need be few changes should be made as we need to achieve the requirement by using **Separate Environments (like dev, Staging, Prod)** and we can also use **Provider Aliases**.

**My file structure:**

```
├── dev/
│   └── main.tf
├── shared-env/
│   └── main.tf
└── modules/
    └── azurevpn-keyvault/
        └── main.tf
```

**My demo terraform configuration:**

**Module: azurevpn-keyvault** (`./modules/azurevpn-keyvault/main.tf`):

```
variable "keyvault_name" {
  description = "Name of the Key Vault"
  type        = string
}

variable "dns_zone_name" {
  description = "Name of the DNS Zone"
  type        = string
}

variable "dns_zone_rg" {
  description = "Resource Group of the DNS Zone"
  type        = string
}

variable "a_record" {
  description = "Boolean to determine if A record should be created"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias   = "default"
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias   = "shared_env"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "keyvault_pep_record" {
  count               = var.a_record ? 1 : 0
  name                = var.keyvault_name
  zone_name           = var.dns_zone_name
  resource_group_name = var.dns_zone_rg
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = ["10.0.0.1"]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "keyvault_shared_env_pep_record" {
  provider            = azurerm.shared_env
  count               = var.a_record ? 1 : 0
  name                = var.keyvault_name
  zone_name           = var.dns_zone_name
  resource_group_name = var.dns_zone_rg
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = ["10.0.0.2"]
}
```

**Dev Environment** (`./dev/main.tf`):

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features         = {}
  subscription_id  = "YOUR_DEV_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
  tenant_id        = "YOUR_DEV_TENANT_ID"
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias            = "shared_env"
  features         = {}
  subscription_id  = "YOUR_SHARED_ENV_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
  tenant_id        = "YOUR_SHARED_ENV_TENANT_ID"
}

module "azurevpn-keyvault" {
  source = "../modules/azurevpn-keyvault"

  providers = {
    azurerm.default    = azurerm
    azurerm.shared_env = azurerm.shared_env
  }

  keyvault_name = "dev-keyvault-name"
  dns_zone_name = "dev.dns.zone"
  dns_zone_rg   = "dev-dns-zone-rg"
}
```

**Shared Environment** (`./shared-env/main.tf`):

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features         = {}
  subscription_id  = "YOUR_SHARED_ENV_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
  tenant_id        = "YOUR_SHARED_ENV_TENANT_ID"
}

module "azurevpn-keyvault" {
  source = "../modules/azurevpn-keyvault"

  keyvault_name = "shared-env-keyvault-name"
  dns_zone_name = "shared-env.dns.zone"
  dns_zone_rg   = "shared-env-dns-zone-rg"
}
```

Replace `YOUR_DEV_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`, `YOUR_DEV_TENANT_ID`, `YOUR_SHARED_ENV_SUBSCRIPTION_ID`, and `YOUR_SHARED_ENV_TENANT_ID` with your actual values.

Now follow the steps

- Navigate to the `dev`  & `shared-env` directory individually depending on the env you're working on.
- Run `terraform init` to initialize the Terraform configuration.
- Run the `terraform plan` to see the planned changes.
- If everything looks good, run `terraform apply` to apply the changes. Review the plan before confirming.